# Filling index list with correct values

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, np

I have a list of index values. I want to match the index value to the correct information from an np array. How would I do this?

example:

```
index = [1, -2, -2, 0]

#where -2 values are omitted, not present in array

array = ['grape''purple''lizard', 'apple''red''monkey']
```

wanted output:

```
new array = ['apple''red''monkey',-2, -2,'grape''purple''lizard']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension with a test on the bounds of `array`:

```
new_array = [array[i] if 0<=i<len(array) else i for i in index]
```

output: `['appleredmonkey', -2, -2, 'grapepurplelizard']`

*NB. `'apple''red''monkey'` is strictly equivalent to `'appleredmonkey'` due to implicit string concatenation in python.*